# How to differentiate the touch and mouse event in IE 9 and below

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am creating an web application,in which i am giving tooltip support for my control, but the behavior of the tooltip should be different in mouse and touch. So i need to know the source of event, whether it is because of touch or mouse. In IE 11 and IE 10, i can find it through `evt.pointerType`, which returns the source of event. But in IE9 and below, i cant find that out.

Can any one guide me on this.

Thanks

Comment: One small note - how many of your users do you expect to be using both IE9 (and lower) _and_ a touch enabled device?  Is it enough of a problem to worry about, rather than just falling back to the click behaviour for said users?

Comment: Posibly you can't in IE9, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent/pointerType) shows you need at least IE10.